# Avoiding for loop to run linear regression on 3d Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-regression, least-squares

I need to run linear regression in a 3d-Array, for example:-

Array = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5)

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

      [[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])
```

I need to run LR on [0,20,40], [1,21,41] ....[5,25,45]....[19,39, 59]
I am using below code:-

```
LrCalcRate = np.array([])
col_nums = 3
for j in range(Array.shape[1]):
    for i in range(Array.shape[2]):
        y = Array[:, j, i].T
        x = np.arange(col_nums)
        A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
        m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]
        LrCalcRate = np.append(LrCalcRate, -m)
```

Two for loops are taking lot of time, can this be optimized without using for loop.

Comment: This example is not reproducible. Please define `col_nums`, `noisyMeasurementsnp`, etc.

Comment: This looks like you need to use [swapaxes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html#numpy.swapaxes) and start the linear regression from there. But the example is too jumbled to understand, why can't you just reshape appropriately?

Comment: Hi @yatu, i have corrected the code

Answer (score 0):

What you've written is equivalent to

```
x = np.arange(col_nums)
A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
-np.linalg.lstsq(A, a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1))[0][0]
```

For example, using data that produces different slopes for each target:

```
In [9]: a = (np.linspace(0, 2, num=3*4*5)**2).reshape(3,4,5)                                

In [11]: lr_calc_rate = np.array([]) 
    ...: col_nums = 3 
    ...: for j in range(a.shape[1]): 
    ...:     for i in range(a.shape[2]): 
    ...:         y = a[:, j, i].T 
    ...:         x = np.arange(col_nums) 
    ...:         A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T 
    ...:         m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0] 
    ...:         lr_calc_rate = np.append(lr_calc_rate, -m) 
    ...: lr_calc_rate

Out[11]: 
array([-0.91927607, -0.96523987, -1.01120368, -1.05716748, -1.10313128,
       -1.14909509, -1.19505889, -1.24102269, -1.2869865 , -1.3329503 ,
       -1.37891411, -1.42487791, -1.47084171, -1.51680552, -1.56276932,
       -1.60873312, -1.65469693, -1.70066073, -1.74662453, -1.79258834])

In [12]: x = np.arange(col_nums)
    ...: A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
    ...: -np.linalg.lstsq(A, a.reshape(3, -1))[0][0]

Out[12]: 
array([-0.91927607, -0.96523987, -1.01120368, -1.05716748, -1.10313128,
       -1.14909509, -1.19505889, -1.24102269, -1.2869865 , -1.3329503 ,
       -1.37891411, -1.42487791, -1.47084171, -1.51680552, -1.56276932,
       -1.60873312, -1.65469693, -1.70066073, -1.74662453, -1.79258834])
```

Comment: thanks fuglede, can you please explain how this works or can you direct me to it

Comment: Well, it just does exactly what you're doing by hand. From [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html): "If _b_ is two-dimensional, the least-squares solution is calculated for each of the _K_ columns of _b_".